# why my button does not align in the center of my form?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I am using twitter bootstrap library to design a page, unfortunately, my sign up button does not align center with the other elements. Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="Login form">
<meta name="me" content="Med Ayman">
<title>Bootbusiness | Give unique title of the page here</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap responsive -->
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font awesome - iconic font with IE7 support --> 
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/font-awesome-ie7.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootbusiness theme -->
<link href="css/nehalem.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--responsive images-->
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
<img  class="myimg" src="img/logo.png" alt="my logo"/>

<form class="well span4" align="center">
    <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Username"/><br/>
    <input type="password" class="span3" placeholder="Password"/><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary span3">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post your non-boostrap css code

Comment: Would it be possible to get some screenshots of what's going wrong?

Comment: Some of the three classes for your button element has the `float` property, find it and remove it or add new class to button and remove these three.

Comment: my none-bootstrap css document has only one class "myimg" and it concerns the img.

Comment: image posted for you AVP

Comment: @mdesdev , none of the classes has a float attribute. Could you please look at the bootstrap CSS and try to spot the emplacement of the float attribute ?

Comment: use your favorite browser's dom inspector and check what css properties are affecting that button, see if there is some float, margin or something that may be messing that up, maybe the wrapper div has more padding-right than padding-left? it's impossible to tell you the answer without the full code, anything is just a guess

Comment: I don't use frameworks of any kind, I like to know my classes and to have css properties just as many as needed. Try to remove class by class from the button and see which class makes problem and then fix that class, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

The button is actually aligned center, the form inputs are not. Check any additional styling for those, or apply something like this to the inputs:

```
display: block; margin: 0px auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can achieve

```
<img  class="myimg" src="img/logo.png" alt="my logo"/>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 well">
 <form class="">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
 </form>
</div>
```